# Simpledateformat Set to 01

Tags: java, simpledateformat

How can i put 01 in date but not the exact date today in SimpleDateFormat
when I use

```
SimpleDateFormat day= new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
```

the it gives me the exact date today.. so how can i put my specific date for this

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
        String NOW = (sdf.format(new java.util.Date()));
        SimpleDateFormat month = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
        String MONTH = (month.format(new java.util.Date()));
        SimpleDateFormat year = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
        String YEAR = (year.format(new java.util.Date()));
        String PAST = ((MONTH)+"-"+(1)+"-"+(YEAR));
```

the `((MONTH)+"-"+(1)+"-"+(YEAR));` returns `1` but it should be `01` but when I run it it turn into 1 only

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Who taught you to set so many brackets? I find your code hard to read that way. I can much more easily read `MONTH + "-" + 1 + "-" + YEAR`.

Comment: If you really wanted to hand format your date — which you don’t! — you could just do `MONTH + "-01-" + YEAR`.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
YearMonth
.now(
    ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) 
)
.atDay( 1 )
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM-dd-uuuu" )
)
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes. Never use the terrible legacy classes such as `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`.

Get the current year and month.

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.now() ;
```

Get the first day of that month.

```
LocalDate ld = ym.atDay( 1 ) ;
```

Specify you desired formatting pattern.

```
DateTimeFormatter f =  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM-dd-uuuu" ) ;
String output = ld.format( f ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a Date object out of a string representation of a date, then you could use `parse(String source)` method of SimpleDateFormat.

For example:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
Date date = sdf.parse("09-01-2018");
```

Then, as you previosly showed, if you want to format a Date object to a string in a specific format, just invoke:
`sdf.format(date)`.

Note: Be aware that `sdf.parse(String source)` could throw a ParseException if the string is not a valid date.